# Getting ggplot for Python to make a bar chart

Tags: python, python-ggplot

Following [this simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599521/how-do-i-create-a-bar-chart-in-python-ggplot), I am trying to make a dirt simple bar chart using yhat's ggplot python module. Here is the [code suggested previously on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599521/how-do-i-create-a-bar-chart-in-python-ggplot):

```
In [1]:
from ggplot import *
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4], "y":[1,3,4,2]})
ggplot(aes(x="x", weight="y"), df) + geom_bar()
```

But I get an error:

```
Out[1]:
<repr(<ggplot.ggplot.ggplot at 0x104b18ad0>) failed: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ax' referenced before assignment>
```

Comment: The thing about python-ggplot is it's still quite early in development. You can try upgrading to the latest version, which does seem to output something resembling a bar chart, but it still doesn't seem quite right.

Answer (score 0):

This works a newer version of ggplot-python. It's not that pretty (x-axis labels), we really have to work on that :-(