# geom_bar() of ggplot in Python displaying all bars as having heights of unity

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm looking to plot of the below dataframe `median_area` against `disturbance_code` in year 2020 using `ggplot` in Python.

```
scenario | year | disturbance_code | median_area
------------------------------------------------
Base     | 2020 | 1001             | 14264
Base     | 2020 | 1002             | 6637
Base     | 2020 | 1003             | 18190
Base     | 2021 | 1001             | 15000
Base     | 2021 | 1002             | 3615
Base     | 2021 | 1003             | 3132
```

My code is, very simply:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ggplot import *

data # this is the dataframe above - it comes from elsewhere in my actual code

ggplot(aes(x = 'disturbance_code', y = 'median_area', fill = 'scenario'), data = 
    data_frame[data_frame['year'] == int(2020)]) +\
    theme_bw() +\
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +\
    labs(x = 'Severity', y = 'Area burned (ha)')
```

This gives the following plot:
[image]

However, what's very strange is that a simple replacement of `geom_bar()` with `geom_line` gives:

[image]

Any help on why this is would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599521/how-do-i-create-a-bar-chart-in-python-ggplot). The answer, in short, is to replace `y = 'median_area'` with `weight = 'median_area'`.